# How to get client id and a client secret from MVC5 in OAuth2?

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am implementing OAuth2 authentication in my MVC 5 application, so I can use it in my Android app. But I am not sure how it all goes, because I never before used Oauth2 or any token authentication.

So far I implemented folowing code in MVC:

## OwinContextExtensions.cs

```
public static class OwinContextExtensions
{
    public static string GetUserId(this IOwinContext ctx)
    {
        var result = "-1";
        var claim = ctx.Authentication.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "UserID");
        if (claim != null)
        {
            result = claim.Value;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

## Startup.Auth.cs

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    static Startup()
    {
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            Provider = new OAuthAppProvider(),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    }
}
```

## OAuthAppProvider.cs

```
public class OAuthAppProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private ProtokolEntities db = new ProtokolEntities();
    public IFormsAuthenticationService FormsService { get; set; }
    public IMembershipService MembershipService { get; set; }


    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        if (MembershipService == null) { MembershipService = new AccountMembershipService(); }

        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var username = context.UserName;
            var password = context.Password;


            var userID = db.aspnet_Users.Where(x => x.UserName == username).SingleOrDefault().UserId.ToString();

            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(username, password))
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
                    new Claim("UserID", userID)
                };

                ClaimsIdentity oAutIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType);
                context.Validated(new AuthenticationTicket(oAutIdentity, new AuthenticationProperties() { }));
            }
            else
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Error");
            }
        });
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        if (context.ClientId == null)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

## Startup.cs.cs

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(PageOffice.Startup))]
namespace PageOffice
{

    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();

            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

When I open Postman and use POST method on http://localhost:1076/token, I open Body -> raw and write

> grant_type=password&password=mypassword&username=myusername

After that I get this as a result:

```
{
    "access_token": "QmmWSh4OZPfC8uv-jyzFzZx1KP05T8b09QlPP3Cy-_Zr9qvWtzWpxNTXOhc4U387N6VHNCnIPklgTEk8CISMyXlcsWAz7MxlRN8qI_Ajg8gjEphHUS1SrO0uDRG2XRqtX1gvTVupym_1xtsdjlwj2VXoc6ySvR0ihb2YjuXnSd4CNgKKaMBQLb1w8P1XB13jc4Pc5tump4-Y4dYn3A5hpvtc9fqpgVAUjZFdiJ_HXMiIpgmqdIFim0Ty8oRZolzpm3RSMPRV6ZIpZBqHG1A2kcdWN-52ZkHuL4_7U743vW0",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 172799
}
```

How do I find this "**client id**" and a "**client secret**" paremeters?
Also I don't really understand how would I use this access_token in android, would the explanation on [this](https://medium.com/@android2ee/oauth-2-on-android-principles-using-google-apis-afb5cc12d935) tutorial be enough?

Thanks for reading and sorry for this much code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an RFC about [OAuth2 for native applications](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps-12). It recommends using the Authorization Code Grant Flow, but without a client secret, because you cannot keep the secret safe in the application binary file.

The Resource Owner Password Credentials flow you are now using (see [OAuth2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3)), should be used only in rare situation when the resource owners can completely trust the application, because the application must know their passwords.

You get or specify the client ID and secret when you register you application (client) at the OAuth2 provider.

The tutorial you linked seems to discuss OAuth version 1, not 2.

Comment: Thanks, I am on the right way now. I sent a wrong link now it is fixed. I think this tutorial would help.

Comment: @Jan Halasa,
 As you mentioned client is and secret can be obtained during the app reg.assume my client is a mobile then I need to hardcore the client id and secret in my code? Or need to store in SQL and compare against the hardocoded values ?