# Implementing OAuth2 in .NET MVC, passing token to action connected to stored procedure

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, oauth-2.0

I am implementing OAuth2 authentication in my MVC 5 application, so I can use it in my Android app. Now I have a problem with action argument, where I pass username and password, I don't understand now how to change this with my token?
Is there a way to decrypt the access token to username and password again on the .net side at all? Because depending of role of the user it will generate different JSON data.

## WebApiController.cs

```
public List<PS_Stored_Procedure_Result> GetUsernamePasswordAll(string userName, string password, int page)
{

    if (MembershipService == null) { MembershipService = new AccountMembershipService(); }

    if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(userName, password))
    {
        var userId = (from u in db.aspnet_Users where u.UserName == userName select u.UserId).SingleOrDefault();

        return db.PS_Stored_Procedure(page, "", "", "", "", userId, 1).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

API I use and works fine with username and pwd:

> http://192.168.100.103:1076/api/SjedniceWebApi/GetSjedniceUsernamePasswordALL?userName=someUsername&password=SomePassword&page=1

My OAuth2 code is in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45546676/how-to-get-client-id-and-a-client-secret-from-mvc5-in-oauth2)

This image below represents current working JSON without the token
[image]

1. I enter username and password and sent it trough API to controller
2. Then it is send to stored procedure for confirmation
3. Gives list of data
4. Returns JSON

My trouble now is with token, I have some concept like in image below:
[image]

From the **step 4** I lose it totally, because I don't know how to say to stored procedure who is the user so it can send me the list back.

I tried in OAuthAppProvider class to add

```
new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username)
```

and later to call

```
 var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

in WebApiController but it returns null?

I would really appreciate at least if someone could tell me if I am going in the right direction with this.

Comment: Is your question how to pass the token to an ActionMethod, rather than passing username and password?

Comment: Yes it is. Because I can't find any better method and I need to pass some kind of info of the user so it can send me the list of json data.

Comment: I updated the question, is there a way maybe to decrypt access token in controller and get username or any other info about the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
public List<PS_Stored_Procedure_Result> GetUsernamePasswordAll(int page)
{
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;

    if (MembershipService == null) { MembershipService = new AccountMembershipService(); }

        var userId = (from u in db.aspnet_Users where u.UserName == identity.Name select u.UserId).SingleOrDefault();

        return db.PS_Stored_Procedure(page, "", "", "", "", userId, 1).ToList();
}
```

After that I just send the token by this link:

> http://localhost:1076/api/data/GetSjedniceUsernamePasswordAll?page=1

In header I put Key -> Authorization and Value -> bearer "the token I got from http://localhost:1076/token "